# No network on a Windows 10 desktop

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

i'm trying to repair a friend's computer, who tells me he doesn't have network since few days. The pc is a desktop running Windows 10, and his motherboard has 3 network cards: 2 Ethernet and 1 Wireless.

Here is what i've seen/tried:

- `ipconfig /all` command doesn't list any network cards, even if they're showned in the windows connections manager.
- None of the 3 cards obtains an ip, or ping access the gateway in static ip mode.
- i tried to reinstall the network cards in the device manager (uninstall the network card, then reboot for auto-reinstall).
- i checked the network cards have no extra protocols (ipv4/ipv6/windows network client/...etc.)
- i tried to access internet wih a linux live CD, with success. Dhcp works fine.
- i tried the 2 following commands: `netsh winsock reset`, and `netsh int ip reset`, without any success. I don't know why, i cant obtain logs for these two commands when i type `netsh winsock reset resetlog.txt` or `netsh winsock reset C:\resetlog.txt`
- `chkdsk` and `scf /scannow` both ended without errors found.
- i did an antivirus scan with BitDefender LiveCD, with no viruses found.

Can someone help me for this problem? Tell me if you need more informations.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect that you're missing drivers I would suggest you download the most up to date drivers from the manufacturer website and start disabling all your network cards one by one and enable them in order to see if all of them works also make sure no firewall comes into interaction if you can provide more info on the hardware and the build your windows you're running on and a result of ipconfig /all after you updated your network cards that would be great

Comment: The motherboard is an Intel DX58So2. I'm not sure the officials intel drivers on the Intel website are compatible with this model.

Comment: Usually most of them are universal worst case you could just uninstall it .

Comment: No, the reinstall of the network drivers or the chipset drivers didnt change anything.

Comment: Well if you can get one of them to work on any other machine you can copy and replace the .inf file with your own I'm certain it's a driver issue did you delete the driver files upon uninstalling ? Try uninstalling them from safe mode or click view > show hidden items in device manager and delete them all

Comment: I tried to uninstall them in Device Manager (i deleted all hidden items in the "nework cards" group.). I also deleted the .inf files. And, i successfully unzipped the drivers package from Intel and succeeded to install them. But again, i see the network cards in ncpa.cpl, but not in ipconfig. I think this is a Windows problem. I'm creating a Dart 10 boot USB, in order to launch a system repair on this system.